# modified SQL query not showing all results

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000

i have a simple query that list clients that have more than one open service job.

```
select link_to_client, count(call_ref) 'Services'
from calls
where call_type='PM'
and last_event_status not in ('RD','C','X')
group by link_to_client
having count(call_ref)>1
```

this produces 11 results.

```
G838AH/24   2
G21/311     2
G328RE/18   29
G328RE      4
G849RJ/6    2
ML110PQ/2   2
G21/505     2
G15PR       2
G21/314     2
ML60BN/2    2
G214AE/12   2
```

i need to add another field to display (link_to_contract_header)

```
select link_to_client, link_to_contract_header, count(call_ref) 'Services'
from calls
where call_type='PM'
and last_event_status not in ('RD','C','X')
group by link_to_client, link_to_contract_header
having count(call_ref)>1
```

but when i add this to the query i only end up with only 9 results

```
ML60BN/2    CLYVAL-2-1  2
G849RJ/6    127-3       2
G21/505     NGLA-1      2
G21/311     NGLA-1      2
G15PR       WOS-1       2
G214AE/12   NGLA-1      2
G328RE      CTSP-1      4
G21/314     NGLA-1      2
G328RE/18   CTSP-1      29
```

so where am i going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your 2 other line you haven't the same `link_to_client, link_to_contract_header,`
if you group by only `link_to_client` then you have the count >1 but if you group by `link_to_client, link_to_contract_header,` the two line deletet dont have count >1

**Update**

you can check the values of `link_to_contract_header` in the 2 line of G838AH/24 (you will find different value)

Comment: OK yeah i see that now.
so what do i need to do to get it to display all 11 results as per the original but with the new field also displayed?

Comment: to Show the 11 results you to make link_to_contract_header equal for the two line not displayed, or accept this result, because you can not show link_to_contract_heade for G838AH/24 and it has two different value

Comment: yup it's a bit of a quandry, as i'm having to account for peoples data entry mistakes!